# Where is the database file stored in Blackberry OS 7 Simulators?

Tags: blackberry, cordova, sqlite, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

I am using phonegap to develop an Application on BB OS 7 simulator.
I am using sqlite and i am mounting a folder as sdcard. But i am not able to find the database which got created in the application. Although it is storing it some where but i dont know where.

Where does it get stored?

Answer (score 1):

your data base saves in SDCard folder itself.if you want to check your data stored or not fallow this path "SDCard\databases\" in this you can find file ,right click on the file and select openwith select  with sqlite ,the database table will opens you can ckeck inserted fields.